# urllib2 and HTTPErrorProcessor Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kodi

I'm trying to change my python code from 2.7 to 3.6

So, I'm not familiar to python but I have error with urllib2
I have this error

```
Error Contents: name 'urllib2' is not defined
```

So I do this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

This is maybe ok, because urllib2 doesn't work on phyton 3?
But I have this:

```
class NoRedirection(urllib2.HTTPErrorProcessor):
   def http_response(self, request, response):
       return response
   https_response = http_response
```

**What I tried to change**

```
class NoRedirection(urlopen.HTTPErrorProcessor):
```

**But does't work. How to fix this?**

```
 **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'HTTPErrorProcessor'**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate module for errors found [`here`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.HTTPError). What you want to do is something along these lines

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError

class NoRedirection(HTTPError):
    ...
```